# Database and user interface software/CMS

Tags: database, content-management-system, frontend, rad

I'm looking for a solution (probably CMS or framework) to make a database and user friendly interface for data entry by regular users.

At our department we're doing a lot of data collection - 6 DBs, 2k records, ~100-200 fields. All of them are powered by in-house Rails application that's hard to maintain on this scale. So, I'm looking for a more tailored solution.

What is important:

- Well-thought database design and data management solution (migrations, validation, etc)
- Almost unlimited customisation (backend and frontend programming), especially an ability to make complex inputs
- Great community to learn and contribute (open source)

What will be nice to have:

- Python/Ruby/etc backend. Modern React (at least not Angular) frontend
- PostgreSQL support
- Plugins, integration with other services

Something I've found: Oracle APEX, MS Access, FileMaker (proprietary), nuBuilder (very limited). After all, I thought about rewriting our app using PostgREST and React or use Plone as a basis (but a bit afraid of ZODB). What do you think?

Any help and advices are appreciated, thx.

Comment: You can check out Directus. https://github.com/directus/directus

Answer (score 4):

PostgreSQL + PostgREST + react-admin

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely look at react-admin, at least for inspiration.

Comment: I'd use admin-on-rest instead, react-admin is dead. https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest

Answer (score 0):

Reactrb  plus rails.  Very simple to use 100% ruby see http://reactrb.org

Comment: That's still a lot of coding and boilerplate. But probably Rails is the best RAD tool for web.

Comment: What is unclear is the nature of the data being inputted and use cases. What other methods of input/output are envisaged..?? I would vote for FileMaker as it would make a really good front end development environment as the database layer is bound to the script GUI environment that is really quick to work in. All the answers (mine included) are just likely to be personal opinions reather than attempts to deconstruct your requirements...